# File Scoped Variables

Tags: xslt, global-variables

Have the need for a variable I can access from any template.

I've got a global template at the start of the file that's always called. I want to be able to access this variable in the templates that are called when apply-templates is ran.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a good summary of my problem. I've got various templates that are called (in various orders). They put form controls on a page. I have a set of data further down in the XML that I would like to refer to by using an index. Each time I hit one of these templates and are going to render a forum control, I'd like to be able to use this "global" variable as a counter.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing XSLT with various other programming languages.

Comment: Edit your post and show a sample of your XSLT, indicating what you mean by a "global template" and how that relates to the "variable".

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete code example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have the need for a variable I can
>   access from any template.

**The XSLT language provides for [global variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#top-level-variables)** (called *top-level variables*).

Every `<xsl:variable>`, which is a child of `<xsl:stylesheet>` is global and is accessible from within any template or from any other global variable in the complete import tree.

**Here is a small example. This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMyVar" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  From template matching '/': "<xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vMyVar"/>"
  <xsl:call-template name="template2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="template2">
  From template2: "<xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$vMyVar"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to any XML document (not used), produces this result**:

```
  From template matching '/': "3"

  From template2: "3"
```

Comment: Can I modify the variable? I need to use it as a counter of sorts.

Comment: This is a good topic for another question. No, you can't. XSLT is a functional language and its variables are immutable -- once defined they cannot change their value. This, of course, doesn't prevent a very rich and powerful programming style -- on the contrary, it results in even richer, safer and more powerful programming style. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the variable is constant during the transformation, you can make it a global variable by putting it outside the entry template.

If the variable has different values at different times, then you need to use parameters that are set in a calling template and used in a called template. (In XSLT 2.0, you can use tunnel parameters: if these are set in the entry template then they can be used anywhere without having to be passed explicitly through all intermediate template calls).

As a general principle though, it's hard to advise you when you haven't described your problem, only a proposed solution - your level of experience in XSLT is such that the solution you are trying to implement may well not be the most appropriate one.